# Create a tag cloud by wrapping array values in h1 through h6 tags based on a mapping array of weights

Tags: php, arrays, mapping, tag-cloud

I have the following arrays:

```
$artist = ["the roots", "michael jackson", "billy idol", "more", "and more", "and_YET_MORE"];
$count = [5, 3, 9, 1, 1, 3];
```

I want to generate a tag cloud that will have artists with a higher number in `$count` enclosed in `h6` tags and the lowest enclosed `h1` tags.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You will want to add a logarithmic function to it too. (taken from tagadelic, my Drupal module to create tag clouds http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic):

```
db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, id, name FROM ... ORDER BY count DESC');

$steps = 6;
$tags = array();
$min = 1e9;
$max = -1e9;

while ($tag = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $tag->number_of_posts = $tag->count; #sets the amount of items a certain tag has attached to it
    $tag->count = log($tag->count);
    $min = min($min, $tag->count);
    $max = max($max, $tag->count);
    $tags[$tag->tid] = $tag;
}
// Note: we need to ensure the range is slightly too large to make sure even
// the largest element is rounded down.
$range = max(.01, $max - $min) * 1.0001;

foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
    $tags[$key]->weight = 1 + floor($steps * ($value->count - $min) / $range);
}
```

Then in your view or template:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $output .= "<h$tag->weight>$tag->name</h$tag->weight>"
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this algorithm is too skewed toward `<h6>`.  In the sample set: `[5, 3, 9, 1, 1, 3]`, your snippet assigns weight `9` as `<h6>` (good), but then `5` (the next highest) as `<h5>` despite `5` being the midpoint between min value `1` and max value `9`.  Without doing any math, I would assume that weight `5` should be either `<h3>` or `<h4>` (a mid-range tag). You might review my conversion of your answer: https://3v4l.org/dv3gv

Answer (score 34):

Off the top of my head...

```
$artist = array("the roots","michael jackson","billy idol","more","and more","and_YET_MORE");
$count = array(5,3,9,1,1,3);
$highest = max($count);
for (int $x = 0; $x < count($artist); $x++)
{
    $normalized = $count[$x] / $highest;
    $heading = ceil($normalized * 6); // 6 heading types
    echo "<h".$heading.">".$artist[$x]."</h".$heading.">";
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Perhaps this is a little academic and off topic but `hX` tags are probably not the best choice for a tag cloud for reasons of document structure and all that sort of thing.

Maybe `span`s or an `ol` with appropriate class attributes (plus some CSS)?

Answer (score 10):

Have used this snippet for a while, credit is prism-perfect.net. Doesn't use H tags though

```
<div id="tags">
    <div class="title">Popular Searches</div>
    <?php
        // Snippet taken from [prism-perfect.net]

        include "/path/to/public_html/search/settings/database.php";
        include "/path/to/public_html/search/settings/conf.php";

        $query = "SELECT query AS tag, COUNT(*) AS quantity
        FROM sphider_query_log
        WHERE results > 0
        GROUP BY query
        ORDER BY query ASC
        LIMIT 10";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $tags[$row['tag']] = $row['quantity'];
        }

        // change these font sizes if you will
        $max_size = 30; // max font size in %
        $min_size = 11; // min font size in %

        // get the largest and smallest array values
        $max_qty = max(array_values($tags));
        $min_qty = min(array_values($tags));

        // find the range of values
        $spread = $max_qty - $min_qty;
        if (0 == $spread) { // we don't want to divide by zero
            $spread = 1;
        }

        // determine the font-size increment
        // this is the increase per tag quantity (times used)
        $step = ($max_size - $min_size)/($spread);

        // loop through our tag array
        foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {

            // calculate CSS font-size
            // find the $value in excess of $min_qty
            // multiply by the font-size increment ($size)
            // and add the $min_size set above
            $size = $min_size + (($value - $min_qty) * $step);
            // uncomment if you want sizes in whole %:
            // $size = ceil($size);

            // you'll need to put the link destination in place of the /search/search.php...
            // (assuming your tag links to some sort of details page)
            echo '<a href="/search/search.php?query='.$key.'&search=1" style="font-size: '.$size.'px"';
            // perhaps adjust this title attribute for the things that are tagged
            echo ' title="'.$value.' things tagged with '.$key.'"';
            echo '>'.$key.'</a> ';
            // notice the space at the end of the link
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems a good approach to me. If your data is in an array just skip the database part. I'd recommend you store the artist name & count in a single associative array. To make that work with the above code use something like:

    $tags = array("the roots" => 5,"michael jackson" = 3,"billy idol" => 9,"madonna" => 1);

I would agree don't use H tags since it messes up your semantics. Spans would be my choice. 

Finally, a helper exists in Zend Framework that may just do what you need. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tag.html

Answer (score 8):

@Ryan

That's correct but it actually makes the tags with the least number, larger.  This code has been tested:

```
$artist = array("the roots","michael jackson","billy idol","more","and more","and_YET_MORE");
$count = array(5,3,9,1,1,3);
$highest = max($count);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($artist); $x++) {
    $normalized =  ($highest - $count[$x]+1) / $highest;
    $heading = ceil($normalized * 6); // 6 heading types
    echo "<h$heading>{$artist[$x]}</h$heading>";
}
```

Comment: The asked question specified that lesser counts should be represented as larger fonts.

Answer (score 3):

This method is for `SQL/PostgreSQL` fanatics. It does the entire job in the database, and it prints text with "slugified" link. It uses Doctrine `ORM` just for the sql call, I'm not using objects. 
Suppose we have 10 sizes:

```
public function getAllForTagCloud($fontSizes = 10)
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT count(tag) as tagcount,tag,slug, 
    floor((count(*) * %d )/(select max(t) from 
        (select count(tag) as t from magazine_tag group by tag) t)::numeric(6,2)) 
         as ranking 
         from magazine_tag mt group by tag,slug", $fontSizes);

    $q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
    return $q->execute($sql);
}
```

then you print them with some CSS class, from .tagranking10 (the best) to .tagranking1 (the worst):

```
<?php foreach ($allTags as $tag): ?>
    <span class="<?php echo 'tagrank'.$tag['ranking'] ?>">
        <?php echo sprintf('<a rel="tag" href="/search/by/tag/%s">%s</a>', 
            $tag['slug'], $tag['tag']
        ); ?>
    </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this is the `CSS`:

```
/* put your size of choice */
.tagrank1{font-size: 0.3em;}
.tagrank2{font-size: 0.4em;}
.tagrank3{font-size: 0.5em;} 
/* go on till tagrank10 */
```

This method displays all tags. If you have a lot of them, you probably don't want your tag cloud to become a *tag storm*. In that case you would append an `HAVING TO` clause to your SQL query:

```
-- minimum tag count is 8 --

HAVING count(tag) > 7
```

That's all

Comment: `echo sprintf()` should never exist in any code for any reason -- this is what `printf()` is for.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a very old post, still I'm posting my view as it may help someone in future.

Here is the tagcloud I used in my website:
http://www.vbausefulcodes.in/

```
<?php
$input= array("vba","macros","excel","outlook","powerpoint","access","database","interview questions","sendkeys","word","excel projects","visual basic projects","excel vba","macro","excel visual basic","tutorial","programming","learn macros","vba examples");

$rand_tags = array_rand($input, 5);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) {
    $size = rand ( 1 , 4 );
    echo "<font size='$size'>" . $input[$rand_tags[$x]] . " " . "</font>";
}

echo "<br>";
$rand_tags = array_rand($input, 7);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++) {
    $size = rand ( 1 , 4 );
    echo "<font size='$size'>" . $input[$rand_tags[$x]] . " " . "</font>";
}

echo "<br>";
$rand_tags = array_rand($input, 5);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) {
    $size = rand ( 1 , 4 );
    echo "<font size='$size'>" . $input[$rand_tags[$x]] . " " . "</font>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a helper in Rails:

```
def tag_cloud (strings, counts)
    max = counts.max
    strings.map { |a| "<span style='font-size:#{((counts[strings.index(a)] * 4.0)/max).ceil}em'>#{a}</span> "  }
end
```

Call this from the view:

```
<%= tag_cloud($artists, $counts) %>
```

This outputs `<span style='font-size:_em'>` elements in an array that will be converted to a string in the view to ultimately render like so:

```
<span style='font-size:3em'>the roots</span>
<span style='font-size:2em'>michael jackson</span> 
<span style='font-size:4em'>billy idol</span> 
<span style='font-size:1em'>more</span> 
<span style='font-size:1em'>and more</span> 
<span style='font-size:2em'>and_YET_MORE</span>
```

It would be better to have a `class` attribute and reference the classes in a style sheet as mentioned by Brendan above.  Much better than using `h1-h6` semantically and there's less style baggage with a `<span>`.

Comment: why did someone give it a -1?

Comment: This question has always been tagged as a PHP question.

Answer (score 0):

With a few trivial mathematical manipulations, the distribution of the sizing can be steered toward a balanced output which is representative of the actual data spread.  The following will ensure that `<h6>` is always used and then if there are at least two unique weighting values in `$count`, then `<h1>` will be used.  Then if there are 3 or more unique weighting values, they will find their relative place in the range between the minimum and maximum values.

Code: ([Demo with several test examples](https://3v4l.org/1UgZT))

```
function balancedTagCloud(array $values, array $priorities): array
{
    $low = min($priorities) - 1;
    $high = max($priorities) - $low;
    return array_map(
        fn($v, $p) => sprintf(
            '<h%1$d>%2$s</h%1$d>',
            ceil(($p - $low) / $high * 6),
            $v
        ),
        $values,
        $priorities
    );
}

echo implode("\n", balancedTagCloud($artist, $count));
```

Output from the sample input:

```
<h4>the roots</h4>
<h2>michael jackson</h2>
<h6>billy idol</h6>
<h1>more</h1>
<h1>and more</h1>
<h2>and_YET_MORE</h2>
```