# How to programatically send input to a java app running in a browser window?

Tags: java, wordle-word-cloud

Consider the most excellent wordle tag cloud generator:

- http://www.wordle.net/create

Entering text into the "textform" textarea and clicking the go button starts up the wordle java applet on that page.  No traffic goes back to the server.

**How can I cause this to happen programmatically?  No hack too cheap!!**

background for this question:

- ["tag cloud" generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574173/tag-cloud-generators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean starting it programmatically from a browser page, you can use the same type of JavaScript that that page uses, which calls the function Wordle.t() to start the applet.

If you want to call it from a Java program, you can download the Wordle.class or jar file yourself, and call the functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of Wordle.

In case anyone finds this page in the future, I thought it would be useful to explain that Wordle invokes its applet by constructing an applet tag with a huge `<param>` containing a sanitized version of whatever text you pasted in. It is the cheapest hack imaginable.